# Headers Include issue

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, header-files

Lets assume I have two forms Form1 and Form2. I need to write in Form2 :

```
Form1^ obj= gcnew Form1();
this->Hide();
obj->Show();
```

And in Form1:

```
Form2^ obj= gcnew Form2();
this->Hide();
obj->Show();
```

but doesnt work because I can't include Form1.h and Form2.h in the two forms at the same time.. any idea?

Comment: Why can't you include both headers in both .cpp files?

Comment: @svick where can these cpp file can be found

Answer (score 0):

Are you in visual studio? You could use #pragma once in the header files, and then you should be able to include them both without problems.

Comment: Yes in VS.. where and how to use #pragma once! in which form do i need to add it.

Comment: Basically you should add it at the top of all include (.h) files. Then you are able to cross-include the header files (Form1.h in Form2.h and Form2.h in Form1.h).